# paypal client authentication failed while going live

Tags: php, wordpress, paypal, payment-gateway

I am getting the following error when trying to use paypal API

```
{"error":"invalid_client","error_description":"Client Authentication failed"}`
```

I have configured the paypal sdk REST API and successfully generated the live app id.

But in the my account page in account eligibiltity for debit credit card and rest of two option when i click enable it show me

> Note: Live credentials are disabled for direct credit card processing
>   in your app. At the moment, we can't enable this based on the
>   information provided. You will be able to try again in 90 days. For
>   more information, please visit the PayPal Help Center.

Is this the problem. what can I do to figure it out ?

One more thing sandbox is working fine.

Comment: could you please show us some code of what are you trying to do? What did you try to solve this?

Comment: Please provided a detailed explanation along with what you have tried (posibly some code that you have tried).

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Yes, this error is going to be your problem. You are attempting to use Rest API to process direct credit card payments, but your account has not been approved to process direct credit card payments using Rest API. That error message means you were either declined for using PayPal Pro via Rest API(the ability to process direct credit card payments), or your Rest application is stuck and still needs to be reviewed. I would suggest contacting PayPal support to have the Rest application escalated for review.